# Deleting a line shape in a excel file using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a line shape in a excel file, named "Line 104". How do I delete this shape or other shape types, line using vba code ?

Comment: Post a sample of the code you've tried. If you haven't tried anything yet, fire up the macro recorder and see what Excel generates when you do it by hand.

Comment: Nothing appears in the macro recorded code related to the line deletion

Comment: Have you tried coming up with something? Give it your best shot, and we'll help fix it, but you won't find people here who will just do it for you.

Comment: Answered: ActiveSheet.Shapes("Line 104").Delete

Comment: Post that as an answer your own question - you get points and it helps the rest of the community. Leaving it here in the comments it gets lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use below piece of code

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Line 104")).Select
Selection.Delete
```

Comment: @amg- you can probable do it without select, see OP's answer

Comment: Yes that is also possible :-)

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy of OP's comment:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Line 104").Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DeleteShape()

Dim sht as Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SampleSheet")

Dim sObject as shape
For Each sObject in ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If sObject.Name = "Line 104" then
     sObject.Select
     Selection.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```